# How to get the maximum row_number in a window in a Spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that looks as below, and I'm using the below mentioned code the get it

```
+---+----------+--------+----------+
|EK |Value     |date    |row_number|
+---+----------+--------+----------+
|5  |100       |1/1/2020|1         |
|5  |150       |1/3/2020|2         |
|5  |175       |1/5/2020|3         |
|62 |200       |2/9/1999|1         |
|62 |21        |9/2/2000|2         | 
+---+----------+--------+----------+

window = Window.partitionBy("EK").orderBy("date")

df.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(window))
```

The expected result is to get the maximum row number in every window as shown below,

```
+---+----------+--------+----------+
|EK |Value     |date    |row_number|
+---+----------+--------+----------+
|5  |175       |1/5/2020|3         |
|62 |21        |9/2/2000|2         | 
+---+----------+--------+----------+
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one more `window` to get the last value.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w1 = Window.partitionBy('EK').orderBy('date')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('EK')

df.withColumn('row_number', f.row_number().over(w1)) \
  .withColumn('last', f.last('row_number').over(w2)) \
  .filter('row_number = last') \
  .show(truncate=False)

+---+-----+--------+----------+----+
|EK |Value|date    |row_number|last|
+---+-----+--------+----------+----+
|5  |175  |1/5/2020|3         |3   |
|62 |21   |9/2/2000|2         |2   |
+---+-----+--------+----------+----+
```

If you don't care about the `row_number`,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('EK')

df.withColumn('last', f.last('date').over(w)) \
  .filter('date = last').show(truncate=False)

+---+-----+--------+--------+
|EK |Value|date    |last    |
+---+-----+--------+--------+
|5  |175  |1/5/2020|1/5/2020|
|62 |21   |9/2/2000|9/2/2000|
+---+-----+--------+--------+
```

and drop `last`.

Comment: your 2nd example will need the df to be sorted first else it will take whatever the last row in the df but not asc nor desc order just like what u said.. need to make it clear a bit

Answer (score 2):

You can create a temporary column with maximum row number by partition, then filter and drop it:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max, row_number


window = Window.partitionBy("EK").orderBy("date")

df = df.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(window))
df = (df
      .withColumn('max_row_number', max('row_number').over(Window.partitionBy("EK")))
      .where(col('row_number') == col('max_row_number'))
      .drop('max_row_number'))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, max('row_number').over(window) just results in the same value as 'row_number'.

Comment: Sorry, in this case it's needed to remove `.orderBy` from window

Comment: Yes, removing the .orderBy works. Thank you!